# How to use translation flags in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm learning how to translate values in angularjs.

I have created a plunker from the example given in [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement)

The plunker link is in here: http://plnkr.co/edit/rkARrvV2tco42VKdfaJI?p=preview

For a quick glance:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
 <p translate="VARIABLE_REPLACEMENT" translate-values="{ name: '&lt;b&gt;example html&lt;/b&gt;'}"></p>
 </div>
```

gives me output as

Hi, **example html** (since `'&lt;b&gt;example html&lt;/b&gt;'` gets translated to **example html**

My expectation is to get a string similar to

Hi, `<b>example html</b>` instead of Hi, **example html**

Any ideas How do I achieve that?

Are there any flags to do the same?

EDIT: I could not find any such flag at the [site](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement)

Answer (score 2):

The documentation has the solution at

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security

where you can set Sanitization Strategy.

like `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize')`